# SELECT COUNT(*) in SQL query

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, linqpad

When converting this LINQ join one-to-many query ([Northwind](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/tree/master/samples/databases/northwind-pubs) sample database):

```cs
from category in Categories
join product in Products
on category.CategoryID equals product.CategoryID
into productGroup
select new {
    CategoryName = category.CategoryName,
    ProductsList = from product in productGroup
                   select product.ProductName
};
```

into SQL, [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) / LINQ introduces a [SELECT COUNT(*)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) on the joined table:

```sql
SELECT [t0].[CategoryName], [t1].[ProductName], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Products] AS [t2]
    WHERE ([t0].[CategoryID]) = [t2].[CategoryID]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [Categories] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Products] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[CategoryID]) = [t1].[CategoryID]
ORDER BY [t0].[CategoryID], [t1].[ProductID]
```

What is the reason for counting joined Products? The result doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: Good question, maybe this is because of the `ProductList` property.  If `ProductList` is an `IQueryable<string>` then IQueryable has method called `.Count()`. SQL Profiler needs to provide the number for this method, that's why you are seeing it.

Comment: @RichárdBaldauf: Makes sense, COUNT doesn't seem related to `join into`, it appears when the projection includes `productGroup`.

Comment: Usually when I' m doing a left outer join I am adding one more line before the select keyword: `from product in productGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()` but be prepare for `NULL` values